# Regular expression in Javascript bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regular expression to do some checking

```
<p>Click the button to do a global search for "h.t" in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = "That's cool!";
var patt1 = /(h.t)/;
var result = str.match(patt1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>
```

the output is **hat,hat** y not **hat** only?

if change to code to

```
var patt1 = /h.t/;
```

The result is fine. I checked in W3schools, and regexr.com but still have no idea on it

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression contains a capturing group, denoted by the parentheses. `match` returns an array of results, where the first item is the *entire* match, and the subsequent entries are the captured groups.  In this case, the group  is the entire regex, hence `hat` being repeated.

If you remove the capturing group, you'll get one entry:

```
var str = "That's cool!";
var patt1 = /h.t/;
var result = str.match(patt1); // ["hat"]
```

Alternatively, if we expand the regex slightly to show the behaviour further:

```
var str = "That's cool!";
var patt1 = /T(h.t)/;
var result = str.match(patt1); // ["That", "hat"]
```

We see that the whole match is the first entry, with the capturing group coming next.

Comment: thanks a lot. I understand the concept now. so it means if 
var patt1 = /((h.t))/ 
it should he ["hat","hat","hat"]

Comment: @wingdf1000 Yes, though I'm not sure how much use such a nested pattern would be in practice :)